# Return list of financial years between date range

Tags: sql-server

Maybe I'm overthinking this, but I'm a bit stumped.

I'm trying to sum up data by month, by financial year, returning one row per financial year, with a column for each month.

I can return one column per month easily, however trying to return the financial years as rows is proving the hard part.

My theory is once I have the financial year selected as a row, I can simply join this into a subquery summed up by financial year/month, giving me 1 per 1.

Trouble is the financial year starts August 1st. The date range of the query can vary from 1 financial year, to a date range that possibly spans 5 years.

For instance, if I had the date range 01/08/2013-31/07/2014, I'd want the financial year to return as:

```
2013/2014
```

If I had the date range 01/08/2012-31/07/2014, I'd want the below returned as financial year:

```
2012/2013 
2013/2014
```

If I had the date range 01/01/2012-28/08/2014, I'd want the below returned as financial year:

```
2011/2012
2012/2013
2013/2014
2014/2015
```

This is my working so far, but it doesn't work as intended.

```
  DECLARE @DateFrom datetime, @DateTo datetime
SET @DateFrom = '2011-08-01'
set @DateTo = '2014-07-31'


; with  FinYr as
        (
        select  @DateFrom as AllDate, @DAteTo as EndDate, case when datepart(MONTH, @DateFrom) < 8 then convert(varchar(4),datepart(year, @DateFrom)-1)+'/'+convert(varchar(4),datepart(year, @DateFrom)) else convert(varchar(4),datepart(year, @DateFrom))+'/'+convert(varchar(4),datepart(year, @DateFrom)+1) End as FinYear
        union all
        select  dateadd(year,1,AllDate) as AllDate, dateadd(year,1,EndDate) as EndDate,case when datepart(MONTH, dateadd(year,1,AllDate)) < 8 then convert(varchar(4),datepart(year, dateadd(year,1,AllDate))-1)+'/'+convert(varchar(4),datepart(year, dateadd(year,1,AllDate))) else convert(varchar(4),datepart(year, dateadd(year,1,AllDate)))+'/'+convert(varchar(4),datepart(year, dateadd(year,1,AllDate))+1) End as FinYear
        from    FinYr
        where   dateadd(year,-1,EndDate) <= convert(datetime,(convert(varchar(4),year(@Dateto))+'-07-31'))
        )
select  AllDate,EndDate, FinYear
from    FinYr
```

Comment: Can you post the ddl and some sample data for FinYr?

Comment: FinYr is not data from the dbase, it is a recursive function.

Comment: Oh good grief....I need more coffee stat!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tally or numbers table for something like this. In my code I have created the tally table on the fly. This is a zero read type of implementation...super fast.

```
DECLARE @DateFrom datetime, @DateTo datetime;
SET @DateFrom = '2011-08-01';
set @DateTo = '2014-07-31';

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )

select CAST(N as CHAR(4)) + '/' +  CAST(N + 1 as CHAR(4))
from cteTally
where N >= DATEPART(YEAR, @DateFrom)
and N <= DATEPART(YEAR, @DateTo);
```

OK with the updated requirements you can accomplish this with just a slight tweak to the above code. This should get you there.

```
select CAST(N as CHAR(4)) + '/' +  CAST(N + 1 as CHAR(4))
from cteTally
where N >= case when DATEPART(MONTH, @DateFrom) > 6 then DATEPART(YEAR, @DateFrom) else DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @DateFrom)) end
and N <= case when DATEPART(MONTH, @DateTo) < 6 then DATEPART(YEAR, @DateTo) else DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @DateTo)) end
```

I think I see what I did wrong there....try this.

```
select CAST(N as CHAR(4)) + '/' +  CAST(N + 1 as CHAR(4))
, case when DATEPART(MONTH, @DateTo) < 8 then DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @DateTo)) else DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @DateTo)) end
from cteTally
where N >= case when DATEPART(MONTH, @DateFrom) > 6 then DATEPART(YEAR, @DateFrom) else DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @DateFrom)) end
and N <= case when DATEPART(MONTH, @DateTo) < 8 then DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @DateTo)) else DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @DateTo)) end
```

Comment: It produces exactly what you stated you wanted as output. What is not correct about it? If you let me know what is not correct I can fix it.

Comment: Hmmm seems close...

If I put in the date range 
'2013-08-01' - '2014-08-20'

Then it returns 2013/2014 and 2014/2015 as expected.

If I put in:
'2013-08-01'- '2014-07-30'

It still returns 2013/2014 and 2014/2015 where in that scenario, it only should reuturn 2013/2014

Comment: Why does the output change? Are your financial years changing on July 1st? Do they ALWAYS change on July 1st? If the switch date is variable then you should be using a calendar table.

Comment: Financial year is always 01/08-31/07

The date range that could be entered can change each time the report is run, so some times it will be reporting on 5 financial years, others just a few months from 1 financial year.

Comment: In your new example I get the following:
    2011/2012
    2012/2013
    2013/2014
    2014/2015
    2015/2016

With the date range of 01/08/2011-31/07/2014 I'd require only 
    2011/2012
    2012/2013
    2013/2014

  as 31/07/2014 is the last day of financial year 2013/2014

Comment: If you understand the code I posted the little tweaks like this shouldn't be too difficult. My concern is that you don't understand this code. You should make certain you know what this does.

Comment: If I'm honest, I don't really understand what your code is doing.
With the latest edit I still sometimes get 1 year too many.
'2011-08-01' to '2012-08-30' gives 2011/2012, 2012/2013 and 2013/2014. 
2013/2014 Shouldn't be included in this date range.

Comment: All you will need to do is adjust the where clause predicates to suit your requirements.

Comment: I've looked again after coffee :)

The below works great and does exactly what I need. Many thanks for your help.

`select CAST(N as CHAR(4)) + '/' +  CAST(N + 1 as CHAR(4))
, case when DATEPART(MONTH, @DateTo) < 8 then DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @DateTo)) else DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @DateTo)) end
from cteTally
where N >= case when DATEPART(MONTH, @DateFrom) <= 7 then DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @DateFrom)) else DATEPART(YEAR, @DateFrom) End
and N < case when DATEPART(MONTH, @DateTo) > 7 then DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @DateTo)) else DATEPART(YEAR, @DateTo) end `

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will show the list of years you wanted:

```
DECLARE 
    @DateFrom datetime, 
    @DateTo   datetime
SET @DateFrom = '2011-01-01'
SET @DateTo = '2014-07-31'


SELECT CAST(YearList AS VARCHAR(4)) + '/' + CAST((YearList +1) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS FiscalYear
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
        DATEPART(YEAR, @DateFrom) - CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @DateFrom) >= 8 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS YearList
    FROM sys.all_objects
  ) q
WHERE YearList <= DATEPART(YEAR, @DateTo) - CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @DateTo) >= 8 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as with the other answer, I get a year too many. Selecting up to 31/07/2014 should only return 2010/2011, 2011/2012, 2012/2013 and 2013/2014 as 31/07/2014 is the last day of financial year 2013/2014.

I actually get 2010/2011, 2011/2012, 2012/2013, 2013/2014 and 2014/2015

Comment: The reason I use a cte for this is because it gives you some control over the values. sys.all_objects can be such a small number it might not have enough rows this.

Comment: Sorry @OWSam, my browser didn't pop up your message and I didn't receive it in time to work on it.  I've edited regardless, for whatever it's worth.  Sean, I thought the same thing in regard to a CTE, but given both the lack of RDBMS specifications in the OP and the probably-low number of fiscal years realistically returnable, went for simple.